# Under the usual metric on $\mathbb R^2$ which of the following sets are compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let $S,T \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be given by

$S=\left\{(x, \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right):0<x\le1\right\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$ and

$T=\left\{(x,x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right):0<x<1\right\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$

Then under the usual metric on $\mathbb R^2$ which of the following sets are compact?

My attempt:
We use Hiene-Borel Theorem: A set is compact in $\mathbb R^2$ iff it is closed and bounded.

Clearly the set $S$ is not closed because for any point $(0,y), -1<y<1$ is also a limit point as for for ball of any radius contains a distinct point, since S doesnot contain all its limit points, it is not closed but it can easily be seen that $S$ is bounded.
Hence not a compact set.

For the set $T$, the only limit point is $(0,0)$ which is contained in the set and the set is bounded, so since $T$ contains all its limit points it is closed and also bounded. Hence $T $ is compact.

Is my argument correct? If not, how should I change my argument and what were the drawbacks in my idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First part is correct. The only mistake in the second part is in stating that $(0,0)$ is the only limit points. Every point is  a limit point of $T$. Also $(1,1\sin 1)$ is a limit point of $T$ which is not in $T$. So $T$ is not compact.

Thanks to 0-th USER for pointing out an error in my earlier answer.

Comment: This is a question from GATE 2006, the ans key says both $S$ and $T$ are compact. Then the ans key is wrong?

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected my answer @0-thUser

Comment: @s1mple Yes, the key answer key is wrong.